# jQuery onClick event "overrides" submit form

Tags: php, jquery

I have a question which I know its a basic one.

I have an html form:

```
<form id="form-contact" name="htmlform" class="styled"  accept-charset="windows-1255,utf-8,iso-8859-1,us-ascii" action= "html_form_send.php" method="post">
```

and jquery onClick event that validates the form fields, related to the same submit-button that submits the form to php file:

```
 <input id="btn-submit" class="btn-submit" type="image" width="60" height="34" src="images/Site_Images/btn_contact.jpg"  name="submit_btn"
```

My jquery code is given below:

```
$('.btn-submit').click(function(e){

    var $formId = $(this).parents('form');
    var formAction = $formId.attr('action');
    defaulttextRemove();
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    $('li',$formId).removeClass('error');
    $('span.error').remove();
    $('.required',$formId).each(function(){
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var $parentTag = $(this).parent();
        if(inputVal == ''){ 
            $parentTag.addClass('error').append('<span class="error">no data in the field</span>');
        }
        if($(this).hasClass('email') == true){
            if(!emailReg.test(inputVal)){
                $parentTag.addClass('error').append('<span class="error">email not accurate</span>');
            }
        }
    });

e.preventDefault();
});
```

---

The behaviour I want is after validated by jquery, if all is OK then submit the form to php. I hope that I'm making sense. Can you show me the right approach for such case?

Thanks.

Comment: trim whitespaces `$.trim` , cause `== ''` is not enough

Comment: Try using a plugin like http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/, or https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation with AJAX.

Comment: defaulttextRemove(); is undefined function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general idea:

```
$('.btn-submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $formId = $(this).parents('form');
        var formAction = $formId.attr('action');
        defaulttextRemove();
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

        $('li',$formId).removeClass('error');
        $('span.error').remove();
        $('.required',$formId).each(function(){
            var inputVal = $(this).val();
            var $parentTag = $(this).parent();
            if(inputVal == ''){ 
                $parentTag.addClass('error').append('<span class="error">no data in the field</span>');
            }
            if($(this).hasClass('email') == true){
                if(!emailReg.test(inputVal)){
                    $parentTag.addClass('error').append('<span class="error">email not accurate</span>');
                }
            }
        });

        if($('*.error',$formId).length) return false;
        else $formId.trigger('submit');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks so what i should do if such will happen sometime is always like u did? check if class error exist then return false; else use trigger submit on the formID?

Comment: Ya, thats the basic idea. Note that the selector could be if($('.error',$formId).length)

Answer (score 2):

just use `$('#form-contact').submit();` in the case all of your validations pass.Its simple.
You can set a js variable to 0 and set it to 1 in case any validation fails.At last you can check if that variable is still 0 and inside that condition just put `$('#form-contact').submit();`

For validation purposes I will recommend you using jQuery Validate
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/
It can validate the data very well and accurate.

Comment: sorry but didnt understand if i use a flag variable i will enter the onClick set it to 1 and then it wont enter onclick again even if the user entered bad data . can u post a change to my code?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than bind to the `click` of the submit button, bind to the `submit` of the form. Try this:

```
$('#form-contact').submit(function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var formAction = $form.attr('action');
    defaulttextRemove();
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

    $('li', $form).removeClass('error');
    $('span.error').remove();
    $('.required', $form).each(function(){
        var $field = $(this);
        var inputVal = $field.val();
        var $parentTag = $field.parent();
        if (inputVal == ''){ 
            $parentTag.addClass('error').append('<span class="error">no data in the field</span>');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if ($field.hasClass('email')) {
            if (!emailReg.test(inputVal)){
                $parentTag.addClass('error').append('<span class="error">email not accurate</span>');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @user1721450 no problem. Don't forget to click the green tick on the left if this answer helped you.

Comment: nope sorry it didnt help... i change the click to submit and tried to debug it ,it never enter the jquery submit function. any other thoughts?

Comment: So you've changed the `click` to `submit`, but have you changed the `.btn-submit` selector to `#form-contact`?